# SQL Server Reporting Services and MHTML email output rendering problems in Outlook 365

Tags: reporting-services, outlook, mhtml

I've got a somewhat elaborate report I put together which looks great when I preview in VS or when I run it from the SSRS portal. Now I'm trying to email it on a routine basis to a dozen people (all internal resources to my company, for now). I'd really like it to display embedded in the email, vs. as an attachment - people don't open attachments, but they're 100x more likely to look at an inline graphic. Unfortunately Outlook (i.e. Word that does the underlying rendering) doesn't support all HTML tags and the report looks like garbage. Here's the report preview vs. what I get in MHTML. I've Googled far and wide, and haven't found a good workaround yet. I believe the most critical failure point is the use of background images in my tables.

I have to believe somebody has come before me and found *some* kind of workaround. Any advice is greatly appreciated!
[image]

[image]

Comment: For instance, is it possible to implement some failback code within my report, so that when delivered to Outlook clients it gets rendered? Like this example:

https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6173-fixed-outlook-background-images

Answer (score 0):

Such things may happen because Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. You can read more about the supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I knew that already though - "Unfortunately Outlook (i.e. Word that does the underlying rendering) doesn't support all HTML tags."

I'm hoping somebody has found a workaround for implementing background images in table cells using some other mechanism, avoiding the unsupported HTML tags.

Comment: @AlsoKnownAsJazz not sure if you can try it, but, test by rendering the report and then take a screenshot or a base64 result and that result add it in the message's body...